# IE 9 BHO addon. Error SCRIPT1014 with loading external JS-file

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer-9, bho, add-on

I'm trying to create simple Internet Explorer 9 addon using .Net and BHO to load external js-file on page and execute it.

I created ieInstance_DownloadComplete (I also tried ieInstance_DocumentComplete, but things were worse) event handler:

```
InternetExplorer explorer = this.ieInstance;
var document = explorer.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
document.parentWindow.execScript(
@"
if (document.getElementById('KCScript') == null)
  {
      var fileref=document.createElement('script');
      fileref.setAttribute('id', 'KCScript');
      fileref.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
      fileref.setAttribute('charset', 'UTF-8')
      fileref.setAttribute('src', 'C:/test.js');
      fileref.onload = function () { eee(); };
      if (typeof fileref!='undefined')
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fileref);}","JavaScript");
  }
```

When page is loaded I can see my test.js attached to page in IE Developer Tools. But function eee() does not raise and i have an error:
"SCRIPT1014: Invalid character
test.js, line 1, character 1"

test.js:

```
function eee()
{
    alert('ttt!');
};
```

test.js is UTF-8, so there is no reading problem.. there is something else

What's wrong? Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to resave JS in "UTF-8 without BOM" encoding
2. Try to place JS to remote server as http://example.com/test.js